# How do I get my If block in visual basic database program to comple all task?

Tags: database, vb.net, if-statement

I have a function coded for on_click operation and it is not cycling all the way through. I have moved various "If" block controls as well as the code itself around several times and I can not figure out how to get it to go all the way through.

As of now, it will check to see if the Company Name is in the database, then check to see if the field is blank, then check to make sure the zip code box is numeric. That's as far as the code goes. I can not get it to cycle through and actually add the row to the database. If I move various lines of codes around, I can get it to add the row, but it will allow the errors such as incorrect zip format as well as blank values also. I need the code to perform the checks, then if all entry is valid, it adds the row.

I am only working on one form as of now, but this exact problem will be applied to several other forms within my overall project. However, if I can not get this one form to work, I will not be able to get the others to work either.

Here is the code in question:

```
    Public Sub AddNewButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddNewButton.Click

    Dim CompanyNameCheck = FinancialAgenciesTableAdapter1.CompanyNameCheck(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    If CompanyNameCheck Is Nothing Then

        If TextBox1.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("Company name field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox1.Focus()
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("Street field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox2.Focus()
        ElseIf TextBox4.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("City field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox4.Focus()
        ElseIf TextBox5.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("State field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox5.Focus()
        ElseIf TextBox6.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("Zip field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox6.Focus()
        ElseIf i < 1 Then
            Try
                Integer.Parse(TextBox6.Text)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Zip field not correct. Please enter only numbers.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                TextBox6.Focus()
            End Try

        Else


            FinancialDepartmentForm.FinancialAgenciesTableAdapter.Insert(Me.TextBox1.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text, Me.TextBox3.Text, _
                                                                           Me.TextBox4.Text, Me.TextBox5.Text, Me.TextBox6.Text, _
                                                                           Me.TextBox7.Text)
            'Me.Validate()
            'refresh the listbox of companies.
            FinancialDepartmentForm.FinancialAgenciesTableAdapter.Fill(FinancialDepartmentForm.FinancialAgenciesDataSet.FinancialAgencies)
            'show message of task completion.
            MsgBox("Addition complete.", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Me.Hide()
            FinancialDepartmentForm.Show()

        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("Company already exist!")
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

The project due date is quickly approaching and I really need some help. I greatly appreciate assistance, for this is something that shouldn't be that complicated. I just have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: What is the error you get? Is that "Zip field not correct. Please enter only numbers."? If that is so, add the ex exception also to your error message and check what is the exception.

Comment: @Manjula I'm not getting any errors. It will just stall like it's loading or such. The quote you put in your comment and the other hard coded message boxes work like they are supposed to. The zip one only pop up when the user puts in non-numbers. The other one is only when the company name field (or other respective fields) is blank.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with a friend, he networked me to a friend of his that was able to help. He added in another variable to keep track of error counting and then used it in a separate If statement that controlled the validation and insertion code. The properly working code is as follows:

```
Public Sub AddNewButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddNewButton.Click

    Dim CompanyNameCheck = FinancialAgenciesTableAdapter1.CompanyNameCheck(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Dim errorCount As Integer

    If CompanyNameCheck Is Nothing Then
        errorCount = 0
        If TextBox1.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("Company name field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox1.Focus()
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("Street field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox2.Focus()
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
        ElseIf TextBox4.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("City field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox4.Focus()
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
        ElseIf TextBox5.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("State field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox5.Focus()
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
        ElseIf TextBox6.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("Zip field blank.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox6.Focus()
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
        ElseIf i < 1 Then
            Try
                Integer.Parse(TextBox6.Text)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Zip field not correct. Please enter only numbers.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                TextBox6.Focus()
                errorCount = errorCount + 1
            End Try

        End If

        If errorCount < 1 Then

            FinancialDepartmentForm.FinancialAgenciesTableAdapter.Insert(Me.TextBox1.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text, Me.TextBox3.Text, _
                                                                           Me.TextBox4.Text, Me.TextBox5.Text, Me.TextBox6.Text, _
                                                                           Me.TextBox7.Text)
            Me.Validate()
            'refresh the listbox of companies.
            FinancialDepartmentForm.FinancialAgenciesTableAdapter.Fill(FinancialDepartmentForm.FinancialAgenciesDataSet.FinancialAgencies)
            'show message of task completion.
            MsgBox("Addition complete.", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Me.Hide()
            FinancialDepartmentForm.Show()

        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("Company already exist!")
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```